# How to add a range of elements of a list to another list in python

Tags: python

I have list let's say `my_first_list = ["A", "M", "F", "T", "_", "D"]`. I want to create another list with these elements: M, F, T so my second list would be `my_second_list = ["M", "F", "T"]`

here is my code but it does not work. sorry I am a beginner.

````
def createProtein(seq):
    my_list = []
    for i in seq:
        if i == "M":
            my_list.append(i)
            if i != "_":
                for j in range(len(my_list)):
                    my_list[j] += i
    return my_list


rframe = ["A", "M", "F", "T", "_", "D"]
print(createProtein(rframe))```
````

Comment: What’s preventing you from just writing `output = ['M', 'F', 'T']`? In other words, what’s the criterion for inclusion? The function name `createProtein` doesn’t really offer any clue …

Answer (score 3):

You can use a slice to extract a range of elements from a list:

```
my_first_list = ["A", "M", "F", "T", "_", "D"]
my_second_list = my_first_list[1:4]
```

This will give:

```
['M', 'F', 'T']
```

If you don't know the indices, but want to use `'M'` and `'_'` as the bounds, you can use:

```
ix1 = my_first_list.index('M')
ix2 = my_first_list.index('_')
my_second_list = my_first_list[ix1:ix2]
```

Comment: Was about to post the same answer, up-voted yours instead. :-) Note that `index` will raise an exception if the value is not found, but that's probably for the best; if your `list` lacks the expected values, you can't very well slice based on them.

Comment: Dear Tom, Thank you so much. as you mentioned I do not know the indices and I want to use a for loop because I do not know whether my first list contains 'M' and '_'. and I want to use them as the bound.

Comment: @ptalebic What I showed will find them if they are present.  If you want to search with a loop, just save the indices and you can still use a slice to extract the range once you know it.

Comment: @ptalebic Another possibility is to wrap the two `find` invocations in a `try`/`except` to check if they're present.  If they are, and if `ix1 < `ix2`, then you're good.  Otherwise you can give an error or do whatever recovery is appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

You are making a huge mistake in your code.

```
def createProtein(seq):
    my_list = []
    for i in seq:
        if i == "M":
            my_list.append(i)
            if i != "_":
                for j in range(len(my_list)):
                    my_list[j] += i
                    print(my_list)
    return my_list


rframe = ["A", "M", "F", "T", "_", "D"]
createProtein(rframe)
# print(createProtein(rframe))
```

**Output**

```
['MM']
['MM']
```

When `i == 'M'`, `my_list` will add 'M'. It will again add an 'M' because of the `j` loop. In the next iteration, `i` will be 'F', hence `i == 'M'` will be false, and no code will be executed after that. Hence finally, `my_list` will be 'MM'.

Your desired code is

```
lis = ['A', 'M', 'F', 'T', '_', 'D']
def index(lis, c):
    for i in range(len(lis)):
        if lis[i] == c:
            return i
def extract(lis, start, end):
    return lis[start : end]
print(extract(lis, index(lis, 'M'), index(lis, '_')))
```

Now you can extract any sub list by passing the start and end characters to `index()` and then to `extract()`
**Output**
['M', 'F', 'T']